# how show image from strorage (Laravel ) in nuxtjs

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, storage, nuxt.js

I want to show all images that are in nuxtjs, i used the strorage (Laravel ) to save the files

```
<img v-for="(row, index) in files" :src="'storage/' + row" :key="index" alt="" width="150px" height="150px" class="img-fluid">
```

The link is as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/storage/example.jpg
```

but nothing show

I tested this before, Don't you think the problem could be from the controller?

```php
public function index()
{
    $files = scandir(storage_path('app/public/'));
    $allFile = array_diff($files, ['.', '..', '.gitignore']);
    return response()->json($allFile, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the image path **you need to specify where your image file exactly is**, so you did most of its part like `:src="'storage/' + row"` but since your actual path to your image is something like `http://localhost:8000/storage/example.jpg` (the base URL of the Laravel app).

### If both Laravel and Nuxt.js app serve under the same port and host

You need a leading slash in your `src` attribute to make an exact path.

```html
<img v-for="(row, index) in files" :src="'/storage/' + row" :key="index" alt="" width="150px" height="150px" class="img-fluid">
```

### If they are not serving on the same host and port

You have to declare an individual variable for your base URL, preferably in `.env` file and then refer to it and prepend it to your image `src` attribute.

So let's say we gonna define it in `.env` file, then it should be something like this:

```
//.env
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/
```

Then we will refer to it in our javascript data method (if that was not exists we will use default value as `'http://localhost:8000/'`).

```js
data: function() {
    return {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8000/ OR http://site.test/'
    }
  }
```

And in the last step we will prepend it to our image `src` attribute just like this:

```html
<img v-for="(row, index) in files" :src="baseURL + 'storage/' + row" :key="index" alt="" width="150px" height="150px" class="img-fluid">
```